# Create Object multiple objects from a array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have created a constructor function

```
  constructor(People) {
    this.PeopleName = People['Name'];
    this.PeopleId = People['Id'];
    this.PeopleGender = People['Gender'];
    this.Peopleunit = People['unit'];

const Name = ["Ashok", "Payal"];
const Id = ["1", "2"];
const Gender = ["M", "F"];
```

Now I have to map all the values that will return new People values as object.How can i pass all these values when we intialize an Object .
Output will be somthing like this.

```
0:{Name:'Ashok', Id: '1', Gender: 'M', unit: '234'}
1:{Name:'Payal', Id: '2', Gender: 'f', unit: '234'}
```

Here Unit will be static.

I have tried for loop to do this but not works for me.Can anyone help me the acheive this objective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through and create object like this:

```
const Name = ["Ashok", "Payal"];
const Id = ["1", "2"];
const Gender = ["M", "F"];
const allPerson = [];

Name.forEach((person, i) => {
    // You can instantiate your People object here
    allPerson.push({"Name": person, "Id": Id[i], "Gender": Gender[i], "unit": '234'})
});

console.log(allPerson);
```

Comment: As Object is already predefined so it wodun't work

Comment: @AnviCreations I am not sure what you are referring here. If you run this code and see console log. I believe that's what your expected output was. Right?

Comment: Flag as duplicate, this is identical to the dupe target noted above.